# Procedure Bodies is now obsolete, MySql .Net Connector

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

I'm getting this warning in my Output window (which doesn't affect functionality but I don't really understand it:

```
Warning: 0 : Use Procedure Bodies is now obsolete.  Use Check Parameters instead
```

I'm using MySql.Data 6.3.7.0 I'd appreciate some help in eradicating it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the libraries' developer marked one of the methods as `[Obsolete]`. This gives a compiler warning as long as you're calling this marked method. `[Obsolete]` attributes are usually used when there is a newer version of said method.

[MSDN Obsolete Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx#Y1710)

Edit:

I've googled some and found one of the commits on the MySQL.Data library.

```
         [Obsolete("Use CheckParameters instead")]
         public bool UseProcedureBodies
         {
           - get { return (bool)values["Use Procedure Bodies"]; }
           - set { SetValue("Use Procedure Bodies", value); }
           + get { return (bool)values["Check Parameters"]; }
           + set { SetValue("Check Parameters", value); }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it for me Alex, however I have no clue what they mean by Procedure Bodies as opposed to Check Parameters, they didn't document this anywhere at least it's not indexed anywhere I've searched for instructions... could you possibly clarify? EDIT: I found it, I was using "use procedure bodies=false" in my connection strings! Thanks Alex